# How many cassette tapes are there, and where are they found?

Tags: resident-evil-7

Before attempting to play through on Madhouse difficulty, I would like to try and make a rough plan of the save points I will be making, as this difficulty limits the number of saves.

So, how many cassette tapes are there in total? And where are they all located?

---

Bonus points for also including a list of 'auto-save' points throughout the game.

Comment: The auto-save thing is completely unrelated and should be a separate question if you're interested in it.

Comment: Here is a guide showing you all (4) of the cassette tapes and their locations: http://www.gosunoob.com/resident-evil-7/re7-vhs-tape-locations/

Comment: @n_palum: They are not the same thing, they are the VHS tapes. The Cassettes I refer to are used for saving the game

Comment: Whoops my bad, wrong thing. As far as I have seen so far I don't think anyone has really tracked how many there are. As for auto-saves it seems those are just checkpoints that are where you respawn after death, not hard saves, which I don't know how they change in Madhouse.

Comment: Can't do full list of cassettes right now, but most save rooms I've encountered so far (up to save room in testing area before "barn fight") have at least 2-3 cassettes each. Also, rarely cassettes may be found as loot in different locations, e.g. recreation room, children's room etc. I will restart my madhouse walkthrough soon (too much resources wasted), so I will try to count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done Madnouse run recently, and kindly noted every cassette tape/autosave locations. This answer may contain spoilers.

I've found totally **30** cassette tapes. All locations in order of accessibility, first number means number of tapes:

Guest House:

- 2: 2nd floor (these are transferred to main game if not used - will be placed in item box);

Main House:

- 2: Laundry Safe Room (1F);
- 1: Recreation Room (2F);
- 2: Safe Room on 1F near basement;
- 1: Processing Area in basement;

Trailer:

- 3;

Old House:

- 2 in Safe Room on water;

Greenhouse:

- 3 on 2F right after entrance;

Main House:

- 1 in Lucas Room (2F);

Testing Area:

- 1: 1F Room with lots wire bombs after 1st 4-legged molded;
- 1: Safe Room on 2F before 'Barn Fight';
- 1: Lucas Control Room;

Boathouse:

- 1 in Safe Room;

Ship:

- 1: 1F room with cassette recorder;
- 1: 3F room with TV;
- 3: 2F 'Guest' Safe Room;

Mines:

- 1: Hut before mine entrance;
- 1: Safe Room (after making necrotoxin);
- 1: Vertical cave where you fight a lot of monster on your way up;
- 1: end of mines - before entrance to last location.

  ---

As for autosave locations, I've tried making notes about them, but not sure if got all of them correctly. I've noted **18** autosaves:

1) Game start;

2) First time seeing Mia lying on bed;

3) After leaving basement;

4) After 1st fight;

5) After killing Mia;

6) After supper with family;

7) (huge gap without autosaves before this one) Enter test area - after watching TV;

8) After making serum;

9) After making serum choice;

10) After boat crash;

11) After initial exploring ship without monsters;

12) Start of Old Videotape;

13) End of Old Videotape;

14) After finding Ethan on S2;

15) After cutscene with Mia giving Ethan bottle;

16) Guest House enter;

17) On attic before 'shockwave' fight;

18) After necrotoxin injection.